# How to implement camera functionality in fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

[image]I have a `button` in a `fragment`. when that `fragment` is called and clicking on that `button` I want the `camera` to open.I have gone through many tutorials. But I couldn't find the solution to implement `camera` in `fragment`.

here is my java code camera.java:

```
public class camera extends Fragment {

private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
Button btnCapture;
ImageView imageView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera,
            container, false);
    btnCapture=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);
    //imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);

    btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent,
                    CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    });

    return rootView;

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            // convert byte array to Bitmap

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0,
                    byteArray.length);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
    }
}
}
```

here is my camera.xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:baselineAligned="false"
tools:context="com.example.prakash.eduqueri.fragments.camera">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
     <!--  Capture picture button
  -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCapturePicture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Take a Picture"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
```

Here is my logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.prakash.eduqueri, PID: 14511
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65636, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.prakash.eduqueri/com.example.prakash.eduqueri.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3367)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3410)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1260)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                              at com.example.prakash.eduqueri.camera.onActivityResult(camera.java:87)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:176)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5437)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3363)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3410) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1260) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

[image]

[image]

new logcat:

```
Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external/images/media/24097: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

04-12 12:43:02.688 29890-29890/com.example.prakash.eduqueri I/Adreno-EGL: : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.2.2.2_RB1.04.04.04.154.004_msm8226_LNX.LA.3.5.2.2.2_RB1__release_AU ()
                                                                          OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.15
                                                                          Build Date: 08/06/14 Wed
                                                                          Local Branch: mybranch4057433
                                                                          Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.2.2.2_rb1
                                                                          Local Patches: NONE
                                                                          Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.2.2.2_RB1.04.04.04.154.004 +  NOTHING
04-12 12:43:02.848 29890-29890/com.example.prakash.eduqueri I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@424bdc50 time:262597724

Comment: At least show what you have done.

Comment: do you rly need to implement the camera itself? why inventing the wheel again if its invented alrdy? start a cameraintent instead and take the taken picture back as a result.

Comment: the camera opens and i am getting an error unable to resume activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to define the onActivityResult in the parent fragment or activity if the current fragment is inside another fragment and the fragment is inside an activity then first define onResultActivity inside the parent fragment and parent Activty. most likely i guess(as you are using viewPager) your fragment is inside some fragment and that parent fragment is inside an activity so follow the following steps:

first define the onActivityResult inside Activity then fragment then the fragment where you are using the camera intent.

onActivityResult in the root parent Activity.

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

Inside the child fragment:

```
  @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    for (Fragment fragment : getChildFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Note: if if your camera intent fragment is inside this fregment then only you have to do this another skip this step.

Now finally implement the onActivityResult in your cameraIntent fragment:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == HomeActivity.RESULT_OK) {
try{
           BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
        // images
        options.inSampleSize = 8;
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                options);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           }
        } else if (resultCode == HomeActivity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
}
```

The fileUri variable is initialized in onClick of button when  the camera intent will start.

Finally one important thing while starting your camera intent you have to use`getParentFragment().startActivityForResult(intent,yourrequestCode);`

so your star intent will look like:

```
  btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
    fileUri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        getParentFragment().startActivityForResult(intent,
                CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

    }
});
```

In above method the fileUri is a String type variable and defined outside the method as it should be used to set the preview of the image as shown in onActivityResult()

Hopefully this will help, if you face any issue do comment, I will help you :) `Have a happy codeing :)`

Comment: I am getting an error in Bitmap bmp=(Bitmap)fileUri.getData() line. It says cannot resolve method getData()

Comment: sorrry my bad forgot to edit the onActivityResult(), check the onActivity Result, Now it will work fine

Comment: null pointer exception at getParentFragment(). When i remove that it works fine and image is storing in sd card successfully. But not able to get image preview

Comment: It means you are not properly handling the onActivityResult in the parent Activity and fragment, to get the preview you have to handle the onActivityResult in parent activity and fragment, as i have shown above

Comment: better way if you prreview the image inside onResume() method, just copy the code inside if(resultCode==...) and copy inside onResume with one if condition as if(fileUri!=null){//past the code coped from onActivityResult}, this will mada a preview of the image, make sure the imageView is public.

Comment: i have posted the new logcat.

Comment: You are using viewpager inside Fragment or Activity?

Comment: did u try my other fix that i mentioned in my above comment, remove onActivityResult() from Fragment and preview image inside onResume lifecycle method.. copy the if(resultCode==..) condition from onActivityResult and past inside the onResume, and replace the if condition with if(fileUri!=null){ your coped code to preview the image}

Comment: So i checked your logcat and found that in MainActivity the intent sent is null, it's because of only one reasion nd that is you already define a fileUri for image before starting the camera intent, now the intent you will get inside the onActivityResult() of your fregment will be null, my suggestion is that dont use the Data variable in your oActivityResult(), for the preview see the eg, as i have done, or replace the line intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); while sending the intent onClick of button, this will prevent the null intent

Comment: thank you so much for helping me. It worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Add this code on your button click.

```
int TAKE_OR_PICK = 1;
                    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(
                            MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    }
```

Override the onActivityResult

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && null != data  && TAKE_OR_PICK == 1) {
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo)
if (imageBitmap != null) {
            try {
                long fileName = System.currentTimeMillis();
                File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "photo_" + fileName + ".jpg");
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                imageBitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, 300, 300, true);
                imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, fileOutputStream);
                fileOutputStream.flush();
                fileOutputStream.close();
                File imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +File.separator + "photo_" + fileName + ".jpg");
                picturePath = imageFile.getPath();
                System.out.println("FILE PATH -> "+picturePath);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the error i was getting is because i didn't had the imagepreview widget in layout file. Now i cleared it.

Comment: how to save the photo i captured to internal memory?

Comment: please check the updated answer.Accept & vote my answer if you help this

Comment: picture is not stored in internal memory.